# Why does SFINAE not give the correct result for incrementing bool?

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits

I wrote an `is_incrementable` trait like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_incrementable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_incrementable<T, std::void_t<decltype(++std::declval<T&>())>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_incrementable_v = is_incrementable<T>::value;
```

When I apply it to `bool` with `-std=c++17` on clang, it returns `true`:

```
// This compiles
static_assert(is_incrementable_v<bool>, "");
```

But incrementing `bool` is not allowed under c++17. Indeed, if I try to do it, I get an error:

```
bool b = false;
++b;
```

results in:

```
error: ISO C++17 does not allow incrementing expression of type bool [-Wincrement-bool]
```

Why does SFINAE report that `bool` is incrementable, when the compiler clearly doesn't allow it?

Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/g/DDFYBf

Comment: It does give the expected static assertion failure in GCC, which is at least a hint that it could simply be a bug in clang.

Comment: @max66 because `operator ++` requires an lvalue

Comment: Yes, beginning to think it's a compiler bug. GCC does seem to do the right thing.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a bug.  If you remove the reference from declval it works for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Clang erroneously permits the incrementation of `bool` values in not-evaluated contexts.

We can simplify your example using C++20 concepts:

```
template<class T>
concept is_incrementable = requires(T t) {
    { ++t };
};

int main() {
    static_assert( is_incrementable<int> );
    static_assert( !is_incrementable<bool> ); // Clang error here
}
```

This program is accepted in GCC and MSVC, but Clang shows the same wrong behaviour here, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YEnKfG8T5

I think it is Clang bug, so submitted a bug report: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52280